# Есть ли плагин для создания подобной палитры?(в блоках НЕ градиент) Верстка без wp

Tags: html, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в блоках НЕ градиент, а равномерный бекграунд.Верстка без wp

Comment: Разрешите полюбопытствовать, что есть "wp"?

Comment: @MedvedevDev wordpress? Но что имел ввиду автор поста, неизвестно

Comment: Имел ввиду не плагин wordpress нужен

Comment: @Sergey Novikov, тоже единственное что пришло в голову, но не понял, что значит "верстка без wp"

Comment: Могу посоветовать bootstrap colorpicker. Применялся в реальном проекте. Полет нормальный.

Comment: как я понимаю, Bootstrap colorpicker не избавит от ручного прописывания цветов, а я интересуюсь как раз генерацией)

Comment: программировть нужно  тогда)